# Scrapy xpath fail to find certain div in a webpage

Tags: xpath, scrapy, lxml

I used Scrapy shell to load this webpage:

```
scrapy shell "http://goo.gl/VMNMuK"
```

and want to find:

```
response.xpath("//div[@class='inline']")
```

However, it returns []. If I use find in chrome inspect of this webpage, I could find 3 of `"//div[@class='inline']"`. Is this a bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This pages's inline stuff is after `</body></html>`...

```
</body></html>
<script type="text/javascript">
var cpro_id="u2312677";
...
```

Here are some things to try:

```
rest = response.body[response.body.find('</html>')+8:]
from scrapy.selector import Selector
Selector(text=rest).xpath("//div[@class='inline']")
```

Comment: Thanks! This works indeed. However, I am not sure about the reason. For example another similar page `http://goo.gl/J522yd` also has what I want after </body></html> but can be correctly located with `response.xpath("//div[@class='inline']")`.

Comment: When html is that broken, all bets are off :) For example the link which works might have some open tag somewhere that makes the parser ignore `</body></html>`. Another solution might be to try Beautifulsoup. 

`from bs4 import BeautifulSoup;
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.body);
results = soup.findAll("div", {"class" : "inline"})`

It might be able to handle this type of broken HTML with more stability. It's trivial to combine scrapy and BeautifulSoup.

Comment: Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [`html5lib`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/html5lib) for parsing the response body, and [work on an `lxml` document using `lxml.html.html5parser`](http://lxml.de/html5parser.html) for example. In the example scrapy shell session below, I had to use `namespaces` to work with XPath:

```
$ scrapy shell http://chuansong.me/n/2584954
2016-03-07 12:06:42 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 1.0.5 started (bot: scrapybot)
2016-03-07 12:06:44 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://chuansong.me/n/2584954> (referer: None)
In [1]: response.xpath('//div[@class="inline"]')
Out[1]: []

In [2]: response.xpath('//*[@class="inline"]')
Out[2]: []

In [3]: response.xpath('//html')
Out[3]: [<Selector xpath='//html' data=u'<html lang="zh-CN">\n<head>\n<meta http-eq'>]

In [4]: from lxml.html import tostring, html5parser

In [5]: dochtml5 = html5parser.document_fromstring(response.body_as_unicode())

In [6]: type(dochtml5)
Out[6]: lxml.etree._Element

In [7]: dochtml5.xpath('//div[@class="inline"]')
Out[7]: []

In [8]: dochtml5.xpath('//html:div[@class="inline"]', namespaces={"html": "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"})
Out[8]: 
[<Element {http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml}div at 0x7f858cfe3998>,
 <Element {http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml}div at 0x7f858cf691b8>,
 <Element {http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml}div at 0x7f858cf73680>]

In [9]: for div in dochtml5.xpath('//html:div[@class="inline"]', namespaces={"html": "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"}):
    print tostring(div)
   ....:     
<html:div xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" class="inline">
<html:span>&#26032;&#28010;&#21517;&#21338;&#12289;&#30021;&#38144;&#20070;&#20316;&#23478;&#29579;&#29667;&#30340;&#21407;&#21019;&#33258;&#23186;&#20307;&#65292;&#8220;&#33433;&#33993;&#26641;&#19979;&#8221;&#30340;&#21448;&#19968;&#29255;&#26032;&#22825;&#22320;&#65292;&#24895;&#20320;&#32654;&#20029;&#20248;&#38597;&#22320;&#36208;&#36807;&#20840;&#19990;&#30028;&#12290;</html:span>
</html:div>

<html:div xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" class="inline">
<html:img src="http://q.chuansong.me/beauties-4.jpg" alt="&#32654;&#20154;&#30340;&#24213;&#27668; &#24494;&#20449;&#20108;&#32500;&#30721;" height="210px" width="210px"></html:img>
</html:div>

<html:div xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" class="inline">
<html:script src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js" async=""></html:script>
<html:ins style="display:inline-block;width:210px;height:210px" data-ad-client="ca-pub-0996811467255783" class="adsbygoogle" data-ad-slot="2990020277"></html:ins>
<html:script>(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});</html:script>
</html:div>
```

Comment: Another valid approach. You can use `html5lib` via `BeautifulSoup` as well with `soup = BeautifulSoup(response.body, "html5lib")`. There are many options :)